# What is the replacement of deprecated if_exist in freemarker

Tags: freemarker

Previously in **freemarker** in could print a field value this way -

```
${mObject?if_exist.fieldValue}
```

Now after deprecating **if_exist**,  **freemarker** suggest to use **!**

For null check now, i can use **!** like -

```
${anotherModelAttribute!} or ${anotherModelAttribute!('default')}
```

But can not really do -

```
 ${mObject!.fieldValue} or something similar
```

When mObject is null it throws exception.

Any approach without null check in `<#if> </#if>` is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
${(mObject.fieldValue)!}
```

Usage of the default value operator with non top-level variables is described [here](http://freemarker.incubator.apache.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#dgui_template_exp_missing_default).

Comment: Thats perfect ! 
Thank you, specially for the doc reference.